# Finfo_file return incorrect type

Tags: php, pdf, mime-types

Good day!

My code return incorrect type for this pdf file. For another pdf file this code is good.

```
    $finfo = @finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime = @finfo_file($finfo, 'upload/123.pdf');
    finfo_close($finfo);

    print_r($mime);
```

This is answer:
application/octet-stream; charset=binary

This is what i need:
application/pdf

This is pdf file
https://dropmefiles.com/x6slw

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was curious, downloaded your file and yes on running your code it didn't give me `application/pdf` but instead `application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

Since the finfo function relies on the file signature (bytes) to find out the file MIME type I made a guess - something must be wrong with the signature so I analyzed it under a Hex-viewer and this is what I found

**Your file**
[image]

**Normal file**
[image]

To be identified properly the PDF signature should be present at the very start but in your file it was offset by 4 bytes. Since finfo could not find the correct MIME type it fell back to its generic *"application/octet-stream; charset=binary"*

**So how to fix?**

I must admit that php's inbuilt functions are pretty good for usual tasks but sometimes here and there you may encounter those "edge case" that's where 3rd party open source libraries come in and here I found which can fix it for you.

**PhpMimeType** : https://github.com/katzien/PhpMimeType

```
$type = \MimeType\MimeType::getType('123.pdf');
print_r($type); //"application/pdf"
                // Yay!
```

Comment: PhpMimeType does not actually check if a file contains a valid pdf content. Instead it relies on the file extension for telling you what type of file it says it is. So, if you wanna make sure an uploaded file, for instance, actually contains pdf in it, PhpMimeType will not help you.